# How do I perform an automation immediately by PHP?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, fuel-sdk, php, automationstudio

I found that can perform an automation immediately on Marketing Cloud via soap API.
(see: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/interacting_with_automation_studio_via_the_web_service_soap_api.htm)
But this sample code is not PHP but C#.
And I cannot find this PHP sample code.

So how do I perform an automation immediately by PHP(Fuel-SDK)?